# white-space: nowrap not working in IE 9

Tags: html, css

I have a table with white-space set to nowrap and columns widths restricted using table-layout fixed. This correctly hides long lines in Firefox, but in IE9 the lines are wrapping.

Test case:

```
<table border="1" width=200 style="white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td style="overflow: hidden;" width=150>Word with some spaces that isnt working in IE</td>
        <td width=50>100/50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="overflow: hidden;" width=150>LoooooooooOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooongword</td>
        <td width=50>550/50</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="overflow: hidden;" width=150>AnotherLoooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnGWord</td>
        <td width=50>660/50</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Firefox:
[image]

IE 9:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the strict **doctype** it works in my IE9, I have the same result as in the firefox. I've tested with the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <table border="1" width=200 style="white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;">
        <tr>
            <td style="overflow: hidden;" width=150>Word with some spaces that isnt working in IE</td>
            <td width=50>100/50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="overflow: hidden;" width=150>LoooooooooOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooongword</td>
            <td width=50>550/50</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="overflow: hidden;" width=150>AnotherLoooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnGWord</td>
            <td width=50>660/50</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```